# How to read .text file from remote system and then write it into array of string in Android?

Tags: android

this is my code:
i'm using ip address of my system which contain listofitems.txt file:

```
    try {
         Create a URL for the desired page
String ipadd=ip.getText().toString();   
        URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.2/listofitems.txt");


        // Read all the text returned by the server
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String str = in.readLine();

        String[] items = new String[]{

        items = str.split(",");

    in.close();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
```

I have tablet connected to system with wireless router(WLAN).
please help!!! thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
try {
            // Create a URL for the desired page
            URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.2/listofitems.txt");

            // Read all the text returned by the server
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            String all=""; 
            String str;
            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                all+=str;
            }
            in.close();

            items = all.split(",");


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
```

And add this to manifest:

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
> </uses-permission>
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" >
> </uses-permission>
> ```

Comment: Do you mean: `String[] items = all.split(",");` on line 14?